# Crystal: Cannot get data for subreport when using JavaBean Connectivity

Tags: java, crystal-reports, javabeans, crystal-reports-2008, subreport

I am using one custom data sources (java bean datasources) for both main report and its subreport
When i am compiling them and preview them seperatly they working fine.

But when i added a subreport to main report . sub report data is not displaying when compiling.

( but in case database data source there is no problem with subreports)

Is there any way to include subreports using java bean datasources?

Comment: Any code you care to share?

Comment: This is get datasource for the report, but it is missing get datasource for subreport. https://www.dropbox.com/s/o33u6zr05nqpptn/DocumentManager.java
Do you have any guide, please help me.